# How can solved it , Assignment problem of integer to array

Tags: java

This is a working piece of code, unfortunately I did not have the Java file but the Class file, then I converted the Class file to Java file, unfortunately at this point I find a problem with the variable j, which has been declared as integer, then an array of type ResouceKey [] is assigned.
Unfortunately there is a problem on these lines, can someone tell me how can I fix it?
thanks

```
if (archivierteResTable.getRowCount() > 0) {
    byte b; int j; 
    ResourceKey[] arrayOfResourceKey; 
    for (j = arrayOfResourceKey = archivierteResTable.getResourceKeys().length, b = 0; b < j; ) { 
        ResourceKey archivierteJahrResKey = arrayOfResourceKey[b];
      rootResKeys.add(archivierteJahrResKey);
      
      b++; }
```

attached an image of the error

[image]

thank you for your help

Comment: This seems to simply be missing a set of parenthesis: `j = (arrayOfResourceKey = archivierteResTable.getResourceKeys()).length`.

Comment: for future reference, post (formatted) code in your question, not images of code.

Comment: I am not quite sure what you are trying to achieve here. That line does not make much sense. You are trying to assign an `ResourceKey[]` to an `int`. An apple is not an orange, how should that work. Also, you have a multi-assignment here (`a = b = c`), is that intended?

Comment: `arrayOfResourceKey` is not of type int (`archivierteResTable.getResourceKeys().length`)

Comment: how to approve the reaction of JoachimSauer because it is the correct solution Thank you once again. The Page has changed a bit.
user15793316 Regarding the decompiler with you another proposal for me because I am currently using jd-gui-windows-1.5.2